# Static Variables in Simulink S-Function Builder

Tags: matlab, static, global-variables, simulink, s-function

I am currently working on the implementation of some C-Code in a Simulink model using the S-Function Builder block.

The code uses various timers and counters, which are defined as static variables to enable the access to the data in following simulation steps.

However, if I start the simulation MATLAB crashes without error message ('Fatal Exception'). To test I defined the variables without the 'static' statement. The Simulation works in this case, however with (logically) wrong results of the S-Function.

Has anybody else faced similar issues or knows how to declare static variables in Simulink?

### P.S.

I know I could use Work Vectors, which I do not intend to do, since it would result in huge efforts in adopting the function to do so.
Furthermore I could simply build a feed-back loop in the model using a memory block. For approximately 100 variables this solution would also be pretty impractical.

Comment: `Fatal Exception` is not an standard error, so something *might* be wrong with your MATLAB. Try running the same code in another computer. Unless the error gives you more information, then please give us that information.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However I get the same problem on my other PC, using the same MATLAB Version and the same compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was a bug in Simulink or the MinGW Compiler. However I tore down the code, ending up with it crashing with the call of one specific variable. I renamed the variable, since I could not find any error in the syntax. Now everything works fine...

The variable name had various underscores and capital letters - in case anyone makes similar experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a possible workaround is to use the **coder.ceval** functionality. I have used this to wrap a C-function with similar (static variables used as counters) function. The coder.ceval call is then placed in an embedded matlab block. Possibly some definitions of the interfaces must also be made (structures / bus objects).
Check coder.ceval, coder.rref and coder.wref for the call structure.